# login system wont log me in no matter what

Tags: php

I am making a login/register system in php.
For some reason in the login.php file i can not login any user.
Bellow is the login.php file. I have the db connection and session start in connect.php file and any function needed in the functios.php file.

```
include("connect.php");
include("functions.php");
if(logged_in())
{
 header("location: profile.php");
 exit();
}

$error = "";



if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

  $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'");
  $retrievePassword=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

     if($count == 1)
     {
       $_SESSION['email']=$email;
       if($checkBox="on")
       {
         setcookie("email",$email,time()+3600);
       }
       header("location: profile.php");
     }
 else
 {
     $error="Emai or Password is inccorect, check again!";
 }

}






<div id="error"><?php echo $error;?></div>
```

```
   <div id="link">
       <a href="index.php">Register</a>
       <a href="login.php">Login</a>
   </div>

   <div id="formDiv">
       <form method="post" action="login.php">
            <label>Email:</label><br>
           <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
            <label>Password:</label><br>
           <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="keep">
           <label>Keep me logged in</label><br><br>
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity> Does the connection `$con` gat anything to do with with a post value `$_POST['email']`?  `$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);` Shouldn't it be just  `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: the mysqli_real_escape_string takes 2 parameters, 1 is the $con and the other is your variable. THE mysqli_real_escape_string  is for security reasons. It for mysql injection attacks

Comment: What about just living it like `$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);`

Comment: you will get mysql errors and you code will not work

Comment: assuming you have validated for duplicates emails. i would suggest      `if($count > 0)  {` instead of     `if($count == 1)  {` which is a more sure way

Comment: i have tried that also and still wont let me in.[link](http://iek-exam.tk/login.php)  here check it out.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: Can you post the markup for your login form? I am going to guess that you don't have something named 'submit'

Comment: i have a submit button but i valued it in login button. As for the password in the registration.php file i make ti a a hash encrypt but in the login file no matter what i do even when i use the password_verify function still wont login.

Comment: Show us the markup.

Comment: i added it in the original post above

Comment: Place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data printed to the screen. Share those results with us.

Comment: Emai or Password is inccorect, check again!
Array ( [email] => ek@gmail.com [password] => 12345678 [submit] => Login )

Comment: What is the password in the database?

Comment: should i relly give you the password?
I dont know if i should...

Comment: Add a `print_r($retrievePassword);` right after you perform the fetch. What does that contain?

Comment: Really? Seriously? Your text password is 123456 and you're worried about giving us the password contained in the database?

Comment: i have stored my files in a domain thats the proble.
Here is the pass 1234567890.
What will it help you with?

Comment: this is the fetch `$retrievePassword=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: If what you shared is correct the passwords *do not match*.

Comment: Do you know how to find your error logs?

Comment: Or the problem could be the cookies you are storing for the `$email` it might be recognizing the stored variable for email. try to unset the '$email' variable first then try again

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard i am sorry, the password you asked for the database is the user OF the database not the user of the login. the Passwords are correct because i have registered also new users and still the same result

Comment: i have deleted the cookie code and still the same, ass for the error log no idea...

Comment: The error logs are on your web server and you need to be able to examine them. They will tell you what is going on, but I can tell you right now that your query is not returning any results because `$retrievePassword` is empty. Go read the links in comments above and you will see how to do this with proper error checking. Right now we are chasing ghosts.

Comment: After deleting the cookie code then unset the `$email` variable. It is still not free i believe. log it out

Comment: i am sure that the email is logged out... as for the log file i will find it now gime me a sec...

Comment: Add this  `or die(mysqli_error());` and see if there is an error . add it here  `$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' and password='$password'") or die(mysqli_error());`

Comment: i deleted the mysqli_fetch_asocc and i deleted the password from the query and it worked.
So the problem is the mysqli_fetch_asocc...

Comment: If you delete the password from the query anybody can login as long as the email is in the database

Comment: i saw the log errors and there is nothing about the problem of the password.
Thank you all for the help now that i know whats exactly the proble i will find a way

Comment: if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["email"]. " " . $row["password"] . "<br>";
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}
$con->close(); 

**bold**I did this just now and it shows everything, email id pass all that we need, so the query work fine, the hell is wrong then?????????

Comment: How many results are you getting back from the query? You're testing for exactly 1, is it possible you have more than one row?

Comment: I really don't get it. Why are you even using num_rows when you're fetching a row? 
I wonder, after you fetched the one single row from a resultset ... and call num_rows ... does it return 1? does it perhaps free the result because it's not needed anymore?
have you tried moving the num_rows one line above?

anyway, i wouldn't num_rows at all.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard In what query exactly?

Comment: @Jacumi The fetching for as i know is only to see if the passwords match, can you explain it better?